# Array vs Dictionary search performance in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, performance, dictionary

I think it's probably a simple answer but I thought I'd quickly check...

Let's say I'm adding `Ints` to an array at various points in my code, and then I want to find if an array contains a certain `Int` in the future..

```
var array = [Int]()

array.append(2)
array.append(4)
array.append(5)
array.append(7)

if array.contains(7) { print("There's a 7 alright") }
```

Is this heavier performance wise than if I created a dictionary?

```
var dictionary = [Int:Int]()

dictionary[7] = 7

if dictionary[7] != nil { print("There's a value for key 7")}
```

Obviously there's reasons like, you might want to eliminate the possibility of having duplicate entries of the same number... but I could also do that with a `Set`.. I'm mainly just wondering about the performance of `dictionary[key]` vs `array.contains(value)`

Thanks for your time

Comment: Are you actually seeing a performance issue or is this just a general question of curiosity? Don't waste time worrying about performance until you have something to worry about. Write readable, maintainable code first.

Comment: Try it and measure....

Comment: It depends on many factors: Does the order of the values matter or not, number of values, frequency of insertions, ...

Comment: try to run this code to measure the performance https://github.com/mfa01/DictionaryVsArrayPerformenceLab

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally speaking, `Dictionaries` provide constant, i.e. O(1), access, which means `searching` if a value exists and updating it are faster than with an `Array`, which, depending on implementation can be O(n). If those are things that you need to optimize for, then a `Dictionary` is a good choice. However, since dictionaries enforce uniqueness of keys, you cannot insert multiple values under the same key.

Based on the question, I would recommend for you to read [Ray Wenderlich's Collection Data Structures](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123100/collection-data-structures-swift-2) to get a more holistic understanding of data structures than I can provide here.

Comment: Good answer and great link ;) For completeness, I would only add that *searching* an unordered `Array` is O(n) operation.

Comment: @PauloMattos Thanks, edited my answer with a little more details about Array search performance

Answer (score 2):

I did some sampling!

I edited your code so that the print statements are empty.

I ran the code 1.000.000 times. Every time I measured how long it takes to access the dictionary and array separately. Then I subtracted the dictTime for arrTime (arrTime - dictTime) and saved this number each time.

Once it finished I took the average of the results.

The result is: 23150. Meaning that over 1.000.000 tries the array was faster to access by 23150 nanoSec.
The max difference was 2426737 and the min was -5711121.

Here are the results on a graph:
[image][image]

Comment: If you ran the entire code, and not the two if statements 1 million times, you aren't just catching the performance of `contains(7)` and `[7]`, you're capturing the allocations and insertions as well. Which is also interesting but may not be what OP intended to measure

Comment: You can check this sample, its show the performance between dict and arrays
https://github.com/mfa01/DictionaryVsArrayPerformenceLab